# MATLAB - Passing a string to a function and loading appropriate data file

Tags: matlab

I have a data file `dataFile.mat` that has two arrays `A_numbers` and `B_numbers`.

I want to write a script that takes gets the data from either `A_numbers` or `B_numbers`. I do not want to use numbers - I need to keep them as strings.

How can I do the following, where `arrayName` can be either `A`  or `B`?

```
function[] = getData('arrayName')
   importedData = load('dataFile')
   result = importedData.arrayName_numbers
   save 'resultData.mat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your function to load all variables saved in `dataFile.mat` which is in the current working directory, and then save only the variable whose name is stored in the string `arrayName "_numbers"` into a new file `resultsData.mat`, the following should do it:

```
function [] = getData( arrayName )

load('dataFile');
save('resultData.mat', [arrayName '_numbers']);

end
```

Testing it:

```
A_numbers = ones(3,1);
B_numbers = ones(3,1).*42;
save('dataFile.mat');

getData('B');
```

This should result in array `B_numbers` being stored in the current working directory in file `resultData.mat`

Comment: Thanks! I realized that my MWE was slightly incorrect - the variable under which the data is stored is of the form `A_numbers` and `B_numbers`. So I want to use the input which is either `A` or `B` to decide whether to look at `A_numbers` or `B_numbers`

Comment: This only requires a trivial change to the example... you need to concatenate the string `"_numbers"` as I've done in the updated example.